# SQL Query to Calculate Daily Percentage

Tags: sql

I have this data in my table:

```
date     time     validity
---------------------------
Day1     07:00     valid
Day1     15:00     valid
Day1     23:00     invalid
Day2     07:00     valid
Day2     15:00     valid
Day2     23:00     valid
Day3     07:00     invalid
Day3     15:00     invalid
Day3     23:00     invalid
```

I want to create an SQL query to calculate the validity percentage for each day. The outcome should look like this:

```
date     percentage
--------------------
Day1     66
Day2     100
Day3     0
```

Below is my failed attempt to get the outcome. In this query, everything seems OK except the part `(SELECT Count(validity) From myTable WHERE validity= 'valid')` causes wrong result because it would count the whole row without grouping it by date.

```
SELECT date, ((SELECT Count(validity) From myTable WHERE validity= 'valid') * 100 / Count(validity)) as percentage
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are completely different RDBMS?

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are really using.

Comment: I'm sorry about the wrong tag. It's been added accidentally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to take the average of only the `valid` values:

```
SELECT date,
       AVG(CASE WHEN validity = 'valid' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS percentage
FROM myTable
GROUP BY date
```

Output:

```
date    percentage
Day1    66.6666
Day2    100
Day3    0
```

This query will run on [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70e435/3) or [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70e43/9).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following using `SUM` with `CASE`. There is no need to use a sub-query to get the count of valid rows.

```
SELECT date, (SUM(CASE WHEN validity = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(validity)) as percentage
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY date
```

Your current sub-query gets the count of all valid rows independent of the groups. You can use a conditional aggregation to get the count / sum of rows per group using `COUNT` / `SUM` with `CASE`.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f7bb162cdb510a0dcae11b0a91e4a53)

Comment: For MySQL, CASE is unnecessary in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to accomplish this

```
select date
       ,count(case when validity='valid' then 1 end)*100.00
        /
        count(validity) as percent
  from table
group by date
```